# Stieltjes integral. Prove alpha is constant

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

If $f$ is Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a, b]$ and if $$\int_{a}^{b}f\,d\alpha=0,$$ for every $f$ which is monotonic on $[a,b]$, prove that $\alpha$ must be constant on $[a,b]$.

My attempt: Use integration by parts $$\int_{a}^{b}f\,d\alpha + \int_{a}^{b}\alpha \,df=\int_{a}^{b}\alpha \,df=f(b)\alpha (b)-f(a)\alpha (a).$$

Since the hipotesis goes for every monotonic function, and given any point $c \in (a,b)$ we may choose the function

$$f =
      \begin{cases}
         0 & \text{if $x < c$} \\
         0 & \text{if $x=c$} \\ 
         1 & \text{if $x >c$} 
      \end{cases}
  $$

So $$\int_{a}^{b}\alpha \, df=\alpha (b).$$

But i can't finish the idea

Comment: Take a look at the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. It will be clear that what counts is the change of the values of the integrator function.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\int_a^b 1_{\{x \geqslant y\}}\,d\alpha = \alpha(b)-\alpha(y)$$

Comment: @LeoLerena:  I am assuming $y$ is any fixed point in $[a,b]$. The indicator function is monotonic. So for any $y \in [a,b]$ we have $\alpha(y) = \alpha(b)$ as was to be shown.